# How to make script send email everyday after date has past if criteria is not met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that collects form responses that need to be checked by employees. I need it to send a reminder email If column A is not checked starting 3 days after the timestamped submission date.

I was able to make the email send 3 days after the timestamp if column A is not checked, but I cannot figure out how to make the script send every day, starting 3 days after the timestamp until column A is checked TRUE.

Here is the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fplP0xdzunRk4e4CRU3-csbyf6iuD8fjpyYUZM2SxfU/edit?usp=sharing

```
function sendDay3ReminderEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1000;   // Number of rows to process
  var numOfColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 
numOfColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  var dt=new Date();
  var dv=new 
Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var reportNumber = row[20];  // 21st column U
    var emailAddress = row[22];  // 23rd column W
    var ssLink= row[23];  // 24th column X
    var message = ("Report #"+reportNumber+" on the Bully Report 
Spreadsheet has been not been reviewed in '3' days. Please review 
the issue and indicate its status once addressed. "+ssLink);      
// sixth column
    var d=new Date(row[21]);// 22nd column V
    if (!row[0] && new 
Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf()==dv) {
      var subject = ("Your attention is needed on Bullying Report 
Number "+reportNumber);
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, the script sends an email if column A is not checked on day 3 after the timestamp. I need it to send every day after day 3 if column A is not checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
if (!row[0] && new 
Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf()==dv)
```

to

```
if (!row[0] && new 
Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf()<=dv)
```

and it should keep sending out the emails after the 3rd day.

The key requirement though is that the email should be sent **once** per day. This can be achieved one of two ways:

1. Make sure the script is invoked only once per day -> Easier way
2. Rewrite the date in column V to next day's date (if the script has write permission) -> Bad choice.

Do revert back with your exact requirement if this does not solve the problem for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was planning on using using a timed trigger to execute the script.

Comment: It works properly with your change as far as I can tell. Thank you so much!